# Design of multipurpose form

Tags: forms, gui-design, design, winforms

Im designing a multipurpose form. Im working on a Windows Application to manage team schedules.
We got a a visual component to represent the events of each person in the team. Something like a calendar. 
When the user right clicks on an event, there are multiple options like erase, get aditional info, share, etc. One of these option is "Modify event" and its used to modify the event properties:

- **Kind of event**   (meeting, holidays, homework, visit a client, etc, etc... its a long list)
- **Start**   (Start datetime of the event)
- **End**     (End   datetime of the event)

The most used action in this form is to change the End property and save.

[image]

This question is because i think im getting lost with this form. 
I wanted to show the old values (before changing anything) all the time, and to let the user change anything without suggest any kind of preference between fields... 
Can any one give me some tips to simplify this form?  (for example im prety sure about changing the datetime format from ISO  to standard)
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the following suggestions :

- Remove the delete button, it should be placed in the right click menu.
- Do not show the original information in the change dialog box, they are already visible in the event list.
- Use a combo box for the Kind of event
- Give the option to the user, to change the date/time directly, without using the date/time picker
- Place date/time on the same line

It may look something like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw7AhM.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: really thanks! i will  U think its a good idea to make "change" button more visible as it is the default option?
I usually use "bold" font, to make it...

Comment: Yes, its a good idea, it will reduce errors.